# LWC Component vertical alignment issue

Tags: slds-grid

I am trying to make the button the same height of the input boxes put together. Below is the pic. I tried using the slds-grid_align_center which didnt make any difference at all.

[image]

Here is my code -

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span><lightning-record-picker variant="label-hidden" label="Parts Family"
                            placeholder="Select a part" object-api-name="Product2" matching-info={matchingInfo}
                            display-info={displayInfo} filter={filter}
                            onchange={handleChange}></lightning-record-picker></lightning-button></span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span><lightning-textarea label="Describe the issue:" placeholder="Describe the issue..."
                            variant="label-hidden"></lightning-textarea></lightning-button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 ">
            <span class="slds-var-p-around_medium slds-grid_align-center"><lightning-button class="slds-float_right"
                    variant="brand" label="Add Part" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you please try to add a class into the div like this: `<div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 slds-var-p-around_medium slds-grid_align-center">
            <span class="slds-var-p-around_medium slds-grid_align-center"><lightning-button class="slds-float_right"
                    variant="brand" label="Add Part" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button></span>
        </div>`

Comment: @Tushar, the above didn't help as it just moved the button vertically to the center. I am trying to make the height of the button same as the two input boxes combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use button instead of lightning-button tag and use css to style it accordingly.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-button_stretch button-style" onclick={handleClick}>
                <div class="label">Add Part</div>
            </button>
```

css:

```
.button-style{
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: #0176d3;
}
.label{
    color: white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When we use CSS styles defined in a component’s style sheet are scoped to the component and CSS cannot reach into the child component of the `lightning-button` component.

So we must first create one external style sheet file and over CSS into it.
I have created `myBtnCSS.css` file and added CSS as below:

```
.my-button > button {
    height: -webkit-fill-available !important;
}
```

After that, I uploaded this file as a static resource in my org.
[image]

Now I can load this CSS file into my LWC component using the below code:
CreateWorkOrderLWCComponent.JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import customStyles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myBtnCSS';

export default class CreateWorkOrderLWCComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api caseId;
    @api veteranEquipmentType;
    isPartSelected = false;
    showDatatable = false;

    selectedPartId;
    selectedPartName;
    @track selectedPartIssue;

    @track selectedParts = [];

    matchingInfo = {
        primarrField: { fieldPath: "Name" },
        additionalFields: [{ fieldPath: "Family" }],
    };
    displayInfo = {
        additionalFields: ["Family"]
    }

    filter = {}; //Initilize blank

    connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, customStyles).then(() => {
            console.log('css loaded');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error to load');
        });
        console.log('this.veteranEquipmentType :: ' + this.veteranEquipmentType);
        //assign the filters
        this.filter = {
            criteria: [
                {
                    fieldPath: 'Family',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: this.veteranEquipmentType,
                },
                {
                    fieldPath: 'IsActive',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: true,
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    handleRecordPickerChange(event) {
        this.selectedPartId = event.detail.recordId;
        this.isPartSelected = this.selectedPartId != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

CreateWorkOrderLWCComponent.HTML:

```
<template>
<div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span><lightning-record-picker variant="label-hidden" label="Parts Family"
                            placeholder="Select a part" object-api-name="Product2" matching-info={matchingInfo}
                            display-info={displayInfo} filter={filter}
                            onchange={handleChange}></lightning-record-picker></lightning-button></span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <span><lightning-textarea label="Describe the issue:" placeholder="Describe the issue..."
                            variant="label-hidden"></lightning-textarea></lightning-button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 ">
            <span class="slds-var-p-around_medium slds-grid_align-center">
                <lightning-button class="my-button slds-float_right" 
                    variant="brand" label="Add Part" onclick={handleClick}>
                    </lightning-button>
                    </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

CreateWorkOrderLWCComponent.CSS:

```
lightning-button.my-button {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Final Output:

[image]